# Digital Output Using NI BNC-2110 connect to NI USB-6255

Tags: matlab

I currently have NI BNC-2110 connect to the NI USB-6255 which is then connected to my computer. 
My goal is to generate a digital output through the NI BNC-2110 and then read the output on an analog input on the same NI BNC-2110. (The purpose of this is to make sure that I know how to properly output a digital signal and can input an analog signal, and I figured this would just check both things simultaneously.)

The setup works when generating a digital signal and reading an analog when I use the software NI MAX, my problem is when I try and do the same thing in Matlab.

Here is my current code in Matlab:

```
d = daq.getDevices
s = daq.createSession('ni');

addAnalogInputChannel(s,'dev1', 'ai0', 'Voltage');
s.Rate = 8000;

q = daq.createSession('ni');

addDigitalChannel(q,'dev1','Port2/Line0:0','OutputOnly');

for p = 1:1:100

    outputSingleScan(q,1)
    pause(0.1)
    data = s.inputSingleScan;
    data

    outputSingleScan(q,0)
    pause(0.1)
    data = s.inputSingleScan;
    data

end
```

My current results are an analog input of ~0 Volts, and what I expect is a square wave from my analog input.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. 
I am expecting something with a syntax in Matlab with port to be the problem, but not to sure.